# Why one should not leave fingerprints on bulbs and plugs?

Tags: sparkplugs, lights

I have read that one should not leave greasy fingerprints on their spark plugs or on their light bulbs. Why is this a thing? On what else one should not leave fingerprints? How does one avoid leaving fingerprints (latex gloves or, say, cleaning the light bulb after putting it in)? How do you clean your fingerprints if you leave any?

Comment: What else should one not leave finger prints on?  Wow, it's a pretty extensive list, but I'd say bank vaults and murder victims unless you had a pretty good justification for why they were left there.  A lawyer might have a more comprehensive list!  And one that amuses the geek in me: high vacuum equipment.  Finger grease outgasses, and with scientific grade vacuums, that can actually slow the process of pumping it down because you create a gassious atmosphere of fingerprint that takes *forever* to finally pump out.

Comment: @CortAmmon Please clarify. Do you mean that one should sand down the fingertips of the person one has just murdered, or that one should avoid leaving one's own prints on them? I, er, ... my friend -- definitely my friend -- needs to know this.  Quite urgently, actually.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> Why is this a thing?

For bulbs it is - spark plugs don't care. The problem with getting fingerprints on bulbs (specifically halogen-type bulbs) is actually the grease that gets left behind - the bulb will get quite hot when lit and grease on a portion of the bulb will cause differences in the rate of heating on the bulb surface and thanks to the way materials expand when heated this means you get different parts of the bulb expanding at different rates and... *crack.*

Where the bulbs are made from quartz glass (such as in certain more powerful bulbs from some manufacturers) there is also the issue of devitrification - where the oils/salts left behind in the finger print can potentially cause the material to weaken although typically car bulbs aren't going to get hot enough for this to occur although some fogging of the glass may occur.

> On what else one should not leave finger prints?

Probably a bit broad to answer here I'm afraid.

> How does one avoid leaving finger prints (latex gloves or cleaning say the light bulb after putting it in)?

Yep clean latex gloves (cotton gloves are even better if you have them - but latex or nitrile works just fine) or a holding the bulb in a clean cloth works.

> How do you clean your finger prints if you leave any?

You can clean them afterwards as well, a good wipe down with a clean microfibre cloth will do the job.

Comment: If you don't have glove or a clean cloth, a paper towel works good as well. The ultimate here would be to use cotton gloves, but they aren't nearly as prevalent as latex or nitrile gloves are.

Comment: Clean halogen lights using a glass cleaner, make sure it's dry before you turn it on, that should only take a minute.

Comment: Rubbing alcohol works well if you have touched the bulb.

Comment: And *spark plugs*?? I've never heard of *not leaving finger prints* on spark plugs ... just light bulbs, not spark plugs ... I don't see a way around leaving fingerprints on spark plugs! :o)

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 yep paper towel works for holding it as well - the important thing is for it to be clean. Toilet paper is probably worth avoiding as it can have a tendency to leave small bits of itself behind which can burn on to the bulb surface leading to the same problem. Paper towels are less effective at the "cleaning" bit though - they have a tendency to just push grease around.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I'd actually missed the spark plug bit! You're quite correct that it makes zero difference to a spark plug.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2  +1 for cotton gloves.  I have replaced specialized industrial type halogen bulbs that come with a pair of disposable cotton gloves.

Comment: @DavidWatson - Yes, it's what we've used in the past for projection displays ... a must have in those situations.

Comment: I used to install high capacity halogen bulbs for theater can lights, generally they come in a foam covering, typically we'd hold onto that and pull it off after installation. The same technique works for auto halogens too, provided it comes with a foam covering of course.

Comment: @paulster2 I have checked where I have heard about the spark plugs. Here are 2 sources which can be complete bs as well.  https://www.tomorrowstechnician.com/143319/ 
Says that "Don’t leave greasy fingerprints on the insulator because they can quickly develop into a carbon-tracking and misfire condition." The other is a video 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zsGN9GVjBwo
That claim oily finger prints create hot spots. 
Can you commend on those claims?

Comment: @BaranZadeoglu unless your hands are covered in additional oil/grease it's not going to make a difference, that's probably what the linked article is referring to - bulbs can be tripped up from just the oils from your skin

Comment: @GdD once the glass part of the bulb is **inside** the headlight unit then removing the foam cover from the glass will be challenging... I have always managed to get halogen bulbs fitted by just holding the metal or plastic parts...

Comment: It depends on the car I guess @SolarMike.

Comment: Oils and salts from fingerprints and sweat on halogen bulbs have **nothing to do** with thermal expansion.  Those compounds can precipitate devitrification of the quartz glass which weakens the material and can lead to bulb failure (aka: rupture/explosion).

Comment: @GdD I've had plenty of different cars in my lifetime, but never found any problem with handling halogen bulbs only by the metal base when fitting them. If the bulb is in a cardboard box you have to make sure you open the right end to get hold of the base, but you can usually feel the base through the box before you open it. Of course if you are *removing* a dead bulb it doesn't matter what how you handle that.

Comment: To your edit - **all** halogen bulbs will have a quartz envelope.  These are the only ones you should not touch with ungloved fingers.  Xenon bulbs, for example, are perfectly fine to handle with bare hands.  All halogens will get hot enough for bulb contamination (oil/salts) to be a problem.

Answer (score 7):

Fingerprints on spark plugs aren't a thing, the natural oils on your skin won't affect their operation. If, however, your fingers are covered in car grease or dirt when you handle the plugs then that can cause issues, either interfering with the electrode or the cable connection to the plug terminal.

If you foul the plugs with dirt or grease then clean them before use. Any dirt on the electrode is going to end up in your cylinder!

For halogen lights @Motosubatsu's answer is pretty comprehensive, I would only add to be careful if handling with facial tissues (i.e. Kleenex), which some people do. Some types of tissues have been treated with moisturizers which will contaminate the bulb and cause the same issues as fingerprints. Toilet tissue generally doesn't, neither do paper towels.

Comment: I would say even tissues without moisturizers would be a bad idea. The oils from your fingers would probably go right through a normal tissue

Comment: I tend to use the cardboard box the lamp came in.  I figure its clean enough for the lamp's glass for transit - its clean enough for the install.   Yet another reason why plastic blister packaging sucks.

Answer (score 1):

Despite the two previous answers stating that fingerprints on spark plugs are not a problem, I'll mention that they are.

I have personally replaced plug wires that showed traces of carbon where the spark was "leaking" around the plug due to grease on the plug ceramic. This is especially apparent on aftermarket ignition systems with higher voltage and lightly-coloured (orange) plug wires. Granted these were vehicles modified for competition twenty years ago, however today's ignition systems are on par with those for voltage.